# What's the difference between cloud.spring.io vs docs.spring.io documentation portals?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Surfing documentation I get wither into `cloud.spring.io` vs `docs.spring.io` for documentation.

Assumptions:

> `cloud.*` for spring-cloud

Not: cloud can be at `docs.spring.io`

For instance Spring Cloud Stream on both:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html
- https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html

> One is old

Not: Both are up-to-date.

Who knows? Would be great to have one per GitHub pepo or something that can be deducted from the maven artifact, like group id.

Comment: Spring cloud stream may be updating both, but other spring cloud projects only use docs.spring.io. Find the latest docs here https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Comment: Maven artifact won't work because a project likely had multiple artifacts but one set of docs

Comment: @spencergibb thanks, `spring.io` with reference to the documentation on "learn" tab can be a source of truth but in general, it's a bit confused to have two portals and you always have to pick googling. I use that stack widely and really wondering what is the difference.

Comment: For the projects I lead, docs is right and the other is old